# casperjs: clickLabel кириллица

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Делаю скрейп сайта с Phantom и CasperJS. Пытаюсь задействовать метод `clickLabеl`.

Загвоздка в том, что текст соответствующего элемента написан кириллицей и клик не срабатывает. В отладочных сообщениях вижу только событие `mousedown`, клика нет.

Собственно кириллический текст в сообщении написан вопросиками.

Comment: в casperJS есть параметр --output-encoding. Может поможет?

Comment: нет, ничего не изменилось